# SIP Call established but no voice for both sides

Tags: java, android, sip, voip

I'm developing a SIP client app using Android 4.3.1+ API. I can make a outgoing call and receive a incoming call successfully by using SipDemo sample codes.

Let me show you my makecallWithSipStack method. On the phone side i can see on the screen Call Established with bla bla. At the pc side i havent any problem as well. And i cant see any problem in the logs. But i cant hear voice each side. By the way phone is caller.

Thanks for all advices.

```
public void makecallWithSipStack(){
    SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void onCallEstablished(SipAudioCall call) {
            try {
                call.startAudio();
                call.setSpeakerMode(true);
                updatestatus("Call Established with "+callusername+"@"+calluserdomain);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Make Call","Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCallEnded(SipAudioCall call) {
            try {
                call.endCall();
                call.close();
                updatestatus("Call Ended with "+callusername+"@"+calluserdomain);
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.e("Make Call","Error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    try {
        if (mSipManager != null && mSipProfile !=null){
        call = mSipManager.makeAudioCall(mSipProfile.getUriString(), callusername+"@"+calluserdomain , listener, 30);
        updatestatus("Calling "+callusername+"@"+calluserdomain);}
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Make Call","Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Problem has solved. I forgot one of the permission

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`